# How to show wordpress CPT items in the single page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I defined custome post type (Slug = portfolio).
After a Portfolio post publishes and I click on View post, page not found displays. This is my first problem.
I want when user clicks on a portfolio item it opens in an another page with more details of information. This is my another problem.

This is the code of template page for showing portfolio posts (the name of the page is: portfolio.php)

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Portfolio */
$arg = array('post_type'=>'portfolio');
$loop = new WP_Query($arg);
while($loop->have_posts()):
  $loop->the_post();
  ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">show post</a>
  <br>
<?php  
endWhile;
?>
```

and i have single-portfolio.php with these codes:

```
<?php
$arg = array('post_type'=>'portfolio');
$loop = new WP_Query($arg);
while($loop->have_posts()):
  $loop->the_post();
  ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">show post</a>
  <br>
<?php  
endWhile;
?>
```

please help me

Comment: Go to `Settings` -> `Permalinks` and click on `Save Changes`.

Comment: but i have second problem. single post page shows all posts!!. why?

Comment: The code in your `single-portfolio.php` is wrong. It is the same as the one in `portfolio.php`

Comment: what is the correct code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of your `single-portfolio.php` code could be something like this.

```
<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    endwhile; // End of the loop.
?>
```

Comment: the type of the post is: portfolio. please contain it in your code

Comment: Not necessary to include the name of the `post_type`. Are you sure you've named the file correctly? Also in which URL are you trying to checking the output?

Comment: i remove from the code WP_Query and solved, your answer is correct one. thanks